# Mongo Db getting two documens of a single collection as singel document

Tags: mongodb

I had single collection **Employee**: 
The data inside the collection is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b44cb8b44a531b12aa69678"),
    "Empid" : 1,
    "Empname" : "Raghu",
    "Deptid" : "D1",
    "Depname" : "IT",
    "Salary" : 15000,
    "Time" : "8 Hours"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b44cbda44a531b12aa69679"),
    "Empid" : 1,
    "Empname" : "Raghu",
    "Deptid" : "D2",
    "Depname" : "Soft",
    "Salary" : 25000,
    "Time" : "9 Hours"
}
```

I want the output as

{

```
    "Empid" : 1,
    "Empname" : "Raghu",
{
    "Deptid" : "D1",
    "Depname" : "IT",
        {
    "Salary" : 15000,
         "Time" : "8 Hours"
    }
}
{

    "Deptid" : "D2",
    "Depname" : "Soft",
    {
         "Salary" : 25000,
         "Time" : "9 Hours"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you're expecting is not a valid JSON, please fix that

Comment: You also need to show what you have tried so that it's easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: HI Rubin Porwa,My question was wrong i want the output as below i.e i have posted   "Empid" : 1,
"Empname" : "Raghu",

{ "Deptid" : "D1", "Depname" : "IT", { "Salary" : 15000, "Time" : "8 Hours" } } {

"Deptid" : "D2",
"Depname" : "Soft",
     {
     "Salary" : 25000,
     "Time" : "9 Hours"
     }

}

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following aggregate operation into MongoDB shell.

```
db.employee.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$Empid',
                department: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        Deptid: '$Deptid',
                        Depname: '$Depname',
                        Salary: '$Salary',
                        Time: '$Time'
                    }
                },
                doc: {
                    $first: '$$ROOT'
                },
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                Empid: '$_id',
                EmpName: '$doc.Empname',
                Department: '$department',
                _id: 0
            }
        }

    ]



);
```